# java mail Base64 encoded string to image attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a base64 encoded string which is posted using JSON into a Spring form.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg......etc
```

I want to add this image as an attachment to an email. Attaching the file works fine, but it is just adding the base64 string as the attachment.

I am using the following code to create the attachment part.

```
private MimeBodyPart addAttachment(final String fileName, final String fileContent) throws MessagingException {

    if (fileName == null || fileContent == null) {
        return null;
    }

    LOG.debug("addAttachment()");

    MimeBodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();

    String data = fileContent;
    DataSource ds;
    ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(data.getBytes(), "image/*");

    // "image/*"
    filePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
    filePart.setFileName(fileName);

    LOG.debug("addAttachment success !");

    return filePart;

}
```

I also tried

```
 ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(data, "image/*");
```

How can I convert the base64 string into a proper image file using the ByteArrayDataSource ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll hav to use a Base64-decoder first. With Java 8 you could do:

```
byte[] imgBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
```

With older java-versions you'll have to use some library like apache commons-codec or something - there's lots of those around.

Comment: cool, I will try this:  byte[] blah = Base64.decodeBase64(data.getBytes());

Comment: hi Coen.. did it work for you? I tried this one but i got an empty image in my email.

Answer (score 9):

To avoid decoding and re-encoding you can use the [javax.mail.internet.PreencodedMimeBodyPart](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/PreencodedMimeBodyPart.html) to load your base64 string and attach the PreencodedMimeBodyPart to your message.

```
    private MimeBodyPart addAttachment(final String fileName, final String fileContent) throws MessagingException {
        if (fileName == null || fileContent == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LOG.debug("addAttachment()");
        MimeBodyPart filePart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
        filePart.setContent(fileContent, "image/*");
        LOG.debug("addAttachment success !");
        return filePart;
    }
```

Otherwise, you can use the [javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility::decode](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decode-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-) to wrap the input stream used with your data source but this will decode and re-encode the given data.

```
    private MimeBodyPart addAttachment(final String fileName, final String fileContent) throws MessagingException {
        if (fileName == null || fileContent == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LOG.debug("addAttachment()");
        MimeBodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();

        String data = fileContent;
        DataSource ds;  //Assuming fileContent was encoded as UTF-8.
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        try {
            in = MimeUtility.decode(in, "base64");
            try {
                ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(in , "image/*");
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new MessagingException(fileName, ioe);
        }

        // "image/*"
        filePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        filePart.setFileName(fileName);

        LOG.debug("addAttachment success !");
        return filePart;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i encounter the same issue and I was able to fix it using this code:

//you have to parse the data first to remove "data:image/png;base64" before you can use the decodeBase64(data).

```
byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
ByteArrayDataSource dSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(imgBytes, "image/*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // v = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA........................
String body = v.replace("data:image/png;base64","");                                    
MimeBodyPart filePart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
filePart.setFileName("screenshot.png");
//This is Needed if you want to show as an html element in the page
filePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<screenshot>");
filePart.setText(body);
message.getMimeMultipart().addBodyPart(filePart);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of @jmehrens I was able to attach a file, but they couldn't be opened. Turned out you need to set the datatype seperately and remove it from the given fileContent String:

```
{
   String dataType = StringUtils.substringBetween(file, "data:", ";base64,"); // extract data type (dataType = "image/png") 
base64EncodedFileContent = fileContent.replaceFirst("data:.*;base64,", ""); // remove prefix from fileContent String (base64EncodedFileContent = "iVBORw0KGg......etc"

    MimeBodyPart filePart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
    filePart.setContent(base64EncodedFileContent, dataType);
    filePart.setFileName(fileName);

    return filePart;
 }
```