# I want to fetch details from the uploaded .msg email file converted to base64 String in java, in Spring. How can I do that?

Tags: java, file, email, base64, jakarta-mail

I am using Spring framework. In my application, I want to call an ajax call in angular js to save the .msg file to the DB. In this case I am not able to send the File to the java class so I am sending the Base64 String of it. Now I want to fetch some details from the attached mail like Sender email Id, Subject etc. What are the ways I can do this in java?

Comment: You'd have to decode the string using `java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg)`, then you would need to analyze the decoded msg and retrieve the data you need

Comment: that is what I am asking. is there any jar which I can use to fetch all the details from the decoded base64?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java mail Base64 encoded string to image attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981724/java-mail-base64-encoded-string-to-image-attachment)

Comment: @MebinJoe No. Not duplicate